# Posting to plugin's action controller using Ajax + JSON

Tags: craft3

I want to use Ajax to POST to a plugin endpoint and get a JSON response. The plugin I'm using is for Mailchimp newsletter subscriptions and should allow for JSON responses:

https://github.com/aelvan/mailchimp-subscribe-craft

I have my form:

```
<form action="" method="post" novalidate>
  {{ csrfInput() }}
  <input id="email" name="email" type="email" >
  <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
```

and my Javascript:

```
let json = this.toJSONString(this.form);
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = () => {
  if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
    // ...
  } else {
     // ...
  }
};
xhr.open("POST", "actions/mailchimp-subscribe/audience/subscribe", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
xhr.send(json);
```

This hits the endpoint, but I get a 404 response:

> HTTP 404 – Not Found – yii\web\NotFoundHttpException
>
> Template not found: actions/mailchimp-subscribe/audience/subscribe

As I understand it, I'm correctly posting to the relevent plugin controller action by using the URL `actions/mailchimp-subscribe/audience/subscribe`. Furthermore, if I do a GET to that URL I get a `400` response which would lead me to believe the routing is correct.

The error therefore seems to be in the Craft controller/routing handler. It's not detecting that I've send a JSON string and that I want a JSON response (and not a template/HTML response).

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was I hadn't included the `Accept` header

```js
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

Answer (score 1):

In your newsletter form, you should have:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="mailchimp-subscribe/audience/subscribe">
<input type="hidden" name="language" value="{{ craft.app.locale.id }}">
```

Then, you should POST to `'/' + userLocale` (where `userLocale = $('[name="language"]').val()`).

I am using jQuery, and this is working fine:

```
$.post({
    url: '/' + userLocale,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to do it without jQuery as vanilla JS. Also I don't have any localization. I've tried posting to the root URL with the included hidden inputs but it still throws errors

Comment: To the root URL, you mean `'/'`? Maybe you can also add this to the `<head>` tag: `<base href="{{ alias('@web/') }}">`.